# How to save data added to arraylist saved in SharedPreference

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I use SharedPreferences to pass some data from `Activity1` to `Activity2` when `button` clicked. Then I add these data to `ArrayList` in `Activity2`.

```
//Basically I have ListView with images. 
//When user ckick on any image, Activity1 opens and it contains this image and it's name

Activity1 {

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           String imageName = intent.getStringExtra("name");   //imageName has different vavues, depends on which image user clicked in previous activity.
           int imageId = intent.getIntExtra("image", 0);   //imageId has different vavues, depends on which image user clicked in previous activity.
           String str = Integer.toString(imageId);   //convert imageId to use it as a key in SharedPreferences
           SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

           editor.putString("key", str);  //save current key, 
           editor.putInt(str, receivedImage);
           editor.putString(str + "a", receivedName);
           editor.apply();
    }
}

Activity2{

   onCreate{
      SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      String key1 = sharedPref.getString("key", null);
      String imageName = sharedPref.getString(key1 + "a", null);
      int imageId = sharedPref.getInt(key1, 0);
      mDrinkArrayList.add(new Drink(imageName, imageId));

      listAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, mDrinkArrayList);
      listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      ListView listDrinks = findViewById(R.id.list_drinks);
      listDrinks.setAdapter(listAdapter);
   }
}
```

The problem is that `mArrayList` doesn't save `Data` added before. For example I click on `button` of 3 different images and I expect that `mArrayList` will have 3 `Data` objects. But actually it always has only last `Data` object.
I understand why it happens - SharedPreferences overrides old data. I saw many advices like I have to use different keys but I did it (put imageResourseId as a key). I thought about ways to solve this problem. The ways that I can understand now are:

1) somehow let SharedPreferences to store previous data (I heard about using SQL database, but I don't have so many images to use database).

2) override `mDrinkArrayList` after receiving new data, so it basically have old data when Activity2 starts again.

3) create `mDrinkArrayList` in Activity1, add new Data when button clicked, and pass `mDrinkArrayList` to Activity2 using SharedPreference.

Could someone suggest what shoud I do in this situation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try below solution and let me know in case of concern

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TinyDB](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo) for this approach.

For saving list create an object and save data in your **activity1**

```
TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(context);

tinydb.putList("key", yourIdList));
```

And get your data from **activity2**

```
TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(context);

tinydb.getList("key");
```

Comment: I've already tried to use TinyDB. But it doesn't have putList() method now. It only has putListObject(). Should I use it?

Comment: If you are going to use it you also have to customize the method. For example you are creating a list like; `List<MyModel.class> myList = new Arraylist<>()` and go to your tinyDB class and customize the method `putListObject()`, which means replace **Objects** with **MyModel**

Comment: I'll try your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a better solution to pass whole arraylist  to another activity instead of transfer data and convert in destination.
You can use Serializable data to add Intent and callback it in second activity.
If you need more information about it, let me know.

Comment: Can I use Serializable with SharedPreferences?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Serialized` your `Bean` class like below :-

```
public class YOUR_BEAN_CLASS implements Serializable{


}
```

And than after in your **Activity1**  u need to just pass , yours `Bean` OR `Pojo` like below

```
  startActivity(new Intent(mContext,
  SECOND_ACTIVITY.class).putExtra("YOUR_BEAN", (Serializable) 
  new ArrayList<YOUR_BEAN_CLASS>);
```

And than in the second class **Activity2** u get the "YOUR_ARRAYLIST" as follow

```
ArrayList<YOUR_BEAN_CLASS> categoryList = (ArrayList<YOUR_BEAN_CLASS>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("category");
```